# How to make results like tree by group mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I'm new in mongodb and i have difficult in group data in mongodb.
For example, I have document like this:

```
{
    School: S1
    Department: D1
    Class: C1
    Code: code1
    Time: 7h
},

{
    School: S1
    Department: D1
    Class: C1
    Code: code1
    Time: 8h
},

{
    School: S1
    Department: D1
    Class: C1
    Code: code2
    Time: 7h
},
{
    School: S1
    Department: D1
    Class: C2
    Code: code2
    Time: 7h
},
{
    School: S2 
    Department: D2
    Class: C3
    Code: code1
    Time: 8h
},
{
    School: S2
    Department: D2
    Class: C4
    Code: code2
    Time: 8h
},
{
    School: S2
    Department: D2
    Class: C5
    Code: code3
    Time:9h
}
```

And example of expected result:

```
[
S1: {
    D1: {
        C1: {
            code1: {
                7h : 1,
                8h : 1
            },
            code2: {
                7h: 2
            }

        },
        C2: {
            code2: {
                7h : 1
            }
        }
    }       
},

S2: {
    D2: {
        C3: {
            code1: {
                8h: 1
            }                           
        },

        C4: {
            code2: {
                8h : 1
            }
        },

        C5: {
            code3: {
                9h: 1
            }
        }
    }
}
```

]

I have no ideas where I start write query.

Anybody can have solution for this.

Thank you very much!

Comment: I don't think it would be easy or even fesable do get this result by using aggregation framework. I suggest you look at [mapReduce()](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/map-reduce/) method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `$addToSet` to create array of elements and some `$group` for solve this problem.

It will look like:

```
db.insertTest.aggregate([{$group: {_id: {School: "$School", Department: "$Department", Class: "$Class", Code: "$Code", Time: "$Time"}, countTime:{$sum:1}}}, {$group: {_id:{School:"$_id.School", Department: "$_id.Department", Class: "$_id.Class", Code: "$_id.Code"}, Times: {$addToSet: {Time: "$_id.Time", countTime:"$countTime"}}}}, {$group: {_id:{School:"$_id.School", Department: "$_id.Department",Class: "$_id.Class"}, Codes: {$addToSet: {Code:"$_id.Code", Times:"$Times"}}}}])
```

First group counts number of the same hours, second create array that contains hour and its count, third create array of codes and previous stage.